# Websphere 8.x traverse global JNDI tree

Tags: jndi, global, traversal, websphere-8

Is there an easy way to traverse over the global JNDI tree of one cluster node.
I know the dumpNameSpace.sh script but I want to do this inside a servlet.

I want to list all entries of the global JNDI tree.

Has anyone an idea how to do this on Websphere 8.x?

Answer (score 0):

dumpNameSpace is ultimately just using the Context.list methods, so you could do the same in your servlet.